# how to reset buttons in the game written in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have made a tic-tac-toe game where in i have 9 buttons having attributes. I have not created buttons using  attribute or  attribute. The game firstly creates 9 buttons and later it calls the select Mark button that assigns a mark 'x' or 'o' . CheckIfWinner ..checks the horizontal,vertical and diagonal combinations or a tie and then says either a winner or game over. However, i want to reset the game on clicking on reset button. How to do that. I am unable to figure it out.Please help.

```js
  $(document).ready(startGame);


    function startGame() {
        var blocks = 9;
        var player1 = 'x', player2 = 'o';
        var chance = 1;
        var buttonId = 1;
        var tie = 10;
        var isWinner = false;
        var checkTie = false;
        var cell1, cell2, cell3;
        var buttonKey;
        var outputArray = [];
        var array1, array2, array3, array4, array5, array6, array7, array8, array9;
        var horizontalWinningCombinations = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9],];
        var verticalWinningCombinations = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]];
        var diagonalWinningCombinations = [[1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]];



        for (var index = 0; index < blocks; index++) {
            buttonKey = document.createElement("button");

            if ((index == 3 || index == 6)) {
                lineBreak = document.createElement('br');
                document.body.appendChild(lineBreak);
            }
            buttonKey.id = buttonId;


            buttonKey.setAttribute("value", buttonId);
            buttonKey.setAttribute("text", buttonId);
            buttonKey.style.fontFamily = "Times New Roman";
            buttonKey.style.backgroundSize = "50px";
            buttonAttribute();

           // buttonKey.innerHTML = " + ";
           // buttonKey.style.backgroundColor = "#C0C0C0";
            buttonKey.style.fontSize = "25px";
            buttonKey.style.marginBottom = "10px";
            buttonKey.style.marginLeft = "10px";
            buttonKey.style.marginRight = "10px";
            document.body.appendChild(buttonKey);
            buttonId++;
            document.getElementById("playername").innerHTML = "Player 1 = 'x'";



            buttonKey.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                if (isWinner == true || checkTie == true) {
                    console.log("Game is over!");
                    alert("Game Over!")
                    reset();
                }
                else {
                    selectMark(event, event.srcElement);
                    checkIsWinner();
                }
            });

        }



        function selectMark(currentObject, currentType) {

            if (chance % 2 != 0) {

                document.getElementById("playername").innerHTML = "Current Player: player1 = 'x'" + "<br>" + "<br>";
                document.getElementById("playername").innerHTML += "Next Player: player2 = 'o'";
                outputArray.push([currentType.id]);
                document.getElementById(currentType.id).innerHTML = player1;
                document.getElementById(currentType.id).style.backgroundColor = '#238EE1';
                chance++;
                return;
            }

            document.getElementById("playername").innerHTML = "Current Player :player2 = 'o'" + "<br>" + "<br>";
            document.getElementById("playername").innerHTML += "Next Player: player1 = 'x'"
            outputArray.push([currentType.id]);
            document.getElementById(currentType.id).innerHTML = player2;

            document.getElementById(currentType.id).style.backgroundColor = '#FF1010';

            chance++;
        }


        function checkIsWinner() {

            winningCombinations = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9],
            [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]];

            if (chance == 2) {
                array1 = outputArray[0];

                console.log("array1=" + array1);
            }

            if (chance == 3) {
                array2 = outputArray[1];


                console.log("array2=" + array2);
            }

            if (chance == 4) {
                array3 = outputArray[2];

                console.log("array3 = " + array3);
            }

            if (chance == 5) {
                array4 = outputArray[3];

                console.log("array4 = " + array4);
            }

            if (chance == 6) {
                array5 = outputArray[4];

                console.log("array5 =" + array5);
            }

            if (chance == 7) {
                array6 = outputArray[5];

                console.log("array6 =" + array6);
            }

            if (chance == 8) {
                array7 = outputArray[6];
                console.log("array7 =" + array7);
            }

            if (chance == 9) {
                array8 = outputArray[7];
                console.log("array8 =" + array8);
            }

            if (chance == 10) {
                array9 = outputArray[8];
                console.log("array9 = " + array9);
            }


            isHorizontalWinningCombination();

            isVerticalWinningCombination();

            isDiagonalWinningCombination();

            isTie();


        }

        function isHorizontalWinningCombination() {
            for (var row = 0; row < 3; row++) {

                cell1 = horizontalWinningCombinations[row][0];
                cell2 = horizontalWinningCombinations[row][1];
                cell3 = horizontalWinningCombinations[row][2];

                combinations(cell1, cell2, cell3);
            }

        }

        function isVerticalWinningCombination() {
            for (var row = 0; row < 3; row++) {

                cell1 = verticalWinningCombinations[row][0];
                cell2 = verticalWinningCombinations[row][1];
                cell3 = verticalWinningCombinations[row][2];

                combinations(cell1, cell2, cell3);
            }

        }

        function isDiagonalWinningCombination() {
            for (var row = 0; row < 2; row++) {

                cell1 = diagonalWinningCombinations[row][0];
                cell2 = diagonalWinningCombinations[row][1];
                cell3 = diagonalWinningCombinations[row][2];

                combinations(cell1, cell2, cell3);

            }
        }

        function isTie() {
            tie--;
            if (tie <= 1) {
                console.log("Its a tie. Game Over !");
                checkTie = true;
                alert("Its a Tie. Game Over !")
                return;
            }
        }

        function combinations(cell1, cell2, cell3) {
            if (((array1 == cell1 || array1 == cell2 || array1 == cell3) && (array3 == cell1
                || array3 == cell2 || array3 == cell3) && (array5 == cell1 || array5 == cell2
                    || array5 == cell3))) {

                player1IsWinner();
                return;

            }

            if ((array1 == cell1 || array1 == cell2 || array1 == cell3) && (array3 == cell1
                || array3 == cell2 || array3 == cell3) && (array7 == cell1
                    || array7 == cell2 || array7 == cell3)) {
                player1IsWinner();
                return;
            }
            if ((array1 == cell1 || array1 == cell2 || array1 == cell3) && (array3 == cell1
                || array3 == cell2 || array3 == cell3) && (array9 == cell1
                    || array9 == cell2 || array9 == cell3)) {

                player1IsWinner();
                return;
            }

            if ((array1 == cell1 || array1 == cell2 || array1 == cell3) && (array5 == cell1
                || array5 == cell2 || array5 == cell3) && (array7 == cell1 || array7 == cell2
                    || array7 == cell3)) {

                player1IsWinner();
                return;
            }
            if ((array1 == cell1 || array1 == cell2 || array1 == cell3) && (array5 == cell1
                || array5 == cell2 || array5 == cell3) && (array9 == cell1 || array9 == cell2
                    || array9 == cell3)) {

                player1IsWinner();
                return;

            }
            if ((array5 == cell1 || array5 == cell2 || array5 == cell3) && (array3 == cell1
                || array3 == cell2 || array3 == cell3) && (array7 == cell1 || array7 == cell2
                    || array7 == cell3)) {

                player1IsWinner();
                return;

            }
            if ((array5 == cell1 || array5 == cell2 || array5 == cell3) && (array3 == cell1
                || array3 == cell2 || array3 == cell3) && (array9 == cell1 || array9 == cell2
                    || array9 == cell3)) {

                player1IsWinner();
                return;

            }
            if ((array5 == cell1 || array5 == cell2 || array5 == cell3) && (array7 == cell1
                || array7 == cell2 || array7 == cell3) &&
                (array9 == cell1 || array9 == cell2 || array9 == cell3)) {
                player1IsWinner();
                return;

            }

            if ((array1 == cell1 || array1 == cell2 || array1 == cell3) && (array7 == cell1
                || array7 == cell2 || array7 == cell3) && (array9 == cell1 || array9 == cell2
                    || array9 == cell3)) {

                player1IsWinner();
                return;

            }
            if ((array7 == cell1 || array7 == cell2 || array7 == cell3) && (array3 == cell1
                || array3 == cell2 || array3 == cell3) && (array9 == cell1 || array9 == cell2
                    || array9 == cell3)) {
                player1IsWinner();
                return;

            }

            if ((array2 == cell1 || array2 == cell2 || array2 == cell3) && (array4 == cell1
                || array4 == cell2 || array4 == cell3) && (array6 == cell1 || array6 == cell2
                    || array6 == cell3)) {
                player2IsWinner();
                return;

            }
            if ((array2 == cell1 || array2 == cell2 || array2 == cell3) && (array4 == cell1
                || array4 == cell2 || array4 == cell3) && (array8 == cell1 || array8 == cell2
                    || array8 == cell3)) {
                player2IsWinner();
                return;
            }

            if ((array2 == cell1 || array2 == cell2 || array2 == cell3) && (array8 == cell1
                || array8 == cell2 || array8 == cell3) && (array6 == cell1 || array6 == cell2
                    || array6 == cell3)) {

                player2IsWinner();
                return;
            }
            if ((array8 == cell1 || array8 == cell2 || array8 == cell3) && (array4 == cell1
                || array4 == cell2 || array4 == cell3) &&
                (array6 == cell1 || array6 == cell2 || array6 == cell3)) {

                player2IsWinner();
                return;
            }
        }


        function player1IsWinner() {

            console.log("Player 1 is the Winner");
            alert("Player 1 wins !!")
            isWinner = true;

        }

        function player2IsWinner() {

            console.log("Player 2 is the Winner");
            alert("Player 2 wins!!");
            isWinner = true;
        }


    function reset() {
        $('#reset').on("click",function() {

           buttonAttribute();
           chance=1;
           isWinner=false;
           checkTie=false;
           outputArray=[];
        });
    }
     function  buttonAttribute(){
        buttonKey.innerHTML = " + ";
        buttonKey.style.backgroundColor = "#C0C0C0";
     }
    }
```

```css
    h2 {
        background-color: coral;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #playername {
        text-align: right;

        color: darkred;

    }

    #reset {

        text-align: center;
        font-size: medium;
        float: right;
        position: absolute;
        width: 180px;
        bottom: 350px;
        height: 16px;
        padding: 15px;

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2> Tic-Tac-Toe</h2>
   <div id="playername"></div>
  <div>
 <input type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset"></input>
  </div>
```

Comment: Odd that you can set variables and button-values, but not "reset" (essentially just setting them to nothing/defaults). What's the problem with current reset-function?

Comment: I corrected it , i created a <div id = container></div> and then i appended  the buttons to it and then removed the child element-->while (div.firstChild) {
                        div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
                        
                    }. Here in the code pasted above . i have appended the buttons to the body not the container

Comment: Interesting, just clicking the top left button several times generates the message - player 1 wins!

Comment: can happen. possible. i need to find out the solution